# Are there Providers for Autofac like providers for Ninject?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ninject, autofac

I have a question, Are there Providers for Autofac like providers for Ninject?
I mean, can I use it something like that in Autofac?

```
Bind <ISessionFactory> ().ToProvider(new IntegrationTestSessionFactoryProvider());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm looking at Ninject's [Providers and the Activation Context](http://ninject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Providers%20and%20the%20Activation%20Context) and it appears that Providers are an interface to handle scenarios that Autofac would just handle with a lambda. In Ninject's example, they have:

```
Bind<IWeapon>().ToProvider(new SwordProvider());

abstract class SimpleProvider<T> {
// Simple implementations of the junk that you don't care about...

    public object Create(IContext context) {
        return CreateInstance(context);
    }

    protected abstract T CreateInstance(IContext context);
}

class SwordProvider : SimpleProvider<Sword> {
    protected override Sword CreateInstance(IContext context) {
        Sword sword = new Sword();
        // Do some complex initialization here.
        return sword;
    }
}
```

All this seems like crazy overkill compared to Autofac's delegate syntax:

```
builder.Register(context =>
                      {
                           Sword sword = new Sword();
                           // Do some complex initialization here.
                           return sword;
                      }).As<IWeapon>();
```

EDIT: If your init is complex enough to warrant its own class, you could still do this:

```
builder.RegisterType<SwordFactory>();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<SwordFactory>().Create()).As<IWeapon>();

// this class can be part of your model
public class SwordFactory
{
    public Sword Create()
    {
        Sword sword = new Sword();
        // Do some complex initialization here.
        return sword;
    }
}
```

Nice thing about this is you're still decoupled from your DI framework.

Comment: Well, providers are not typically used in such simple scenarios.. they're often for more complex instantiation requirements, in which a delegate would probably be a poor choice.  I believe you can do the same thing with a delegate as well in Ninject.  Typically you would use a provider when you want to decouple the factory from your DI configuration, this way the factory can exist in your business layer or whatever layer you want.

Comment: You could call to a factory class from the delegate.